# Chrome wallpaper API works with some images, not with others, no apparent reason

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, javascript-debugger

I have written up a quick little chrome extension that grabs a random image from [Wallpaper Abyss](https://wall.alphacoders.com/api.php) and sets it to the chrome os wallpaper. Here is manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Abyss Wallpapers for Chrome OS",
  "description": "Sets the Chrome OS wallpaper to a random wallpaper from the
                      Wallpaper Abyss (wall.alphacoders.com), once a minute",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background":
  {
    "scripts":["jquery-2.2.1.min.js","background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": [
    "wallpaper",
    "https://wall.alphacoders.com/api2.0/",
    "background"
  ]
}
```

And background.js:

```
var baseUrl = "https://wall.alphacoders.com/api2.0/get.php?";
var apiKey = "...";
var params = "auth=" + apiKey + "&method=random";
var interval = 20000;
var XHRinProgress = false;
function doXHR()
{
  console.log("Fired doXHR()...");
  if (XHRinProgress)
  {
    console.log("Another XHR is already in progress...");
    console.log("Exiting...");
    return;
  }
  XHRinProgress = true;
  $.get(baseUrl + params, function(data, status)
    {
      console.log("Entering XHR callback...");
      if (status == "success")
      {
        console.log("XHR connected successfully...");
        if (data.success)
        {
          console.log("Got successful response from the server...")
          var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.wallpapers.length);
          console.log(index);
          console.log("Now setting wallpaper...")
          chrome.wallpaper.setWallpaper
          (
            {url:data.wallpapers[1].url_image,
            layout:"CENTER_CROPPED",
            filename:data.wallpapers[index].id + "." + data.wallpapers[index].file_type},
            function()
            {
              console.log("Enjoy your new wallpaper!")
              XHRinProgress = false;
            }
          )
        }
        else
        {
          console.log("Server returned error...");
          console.log(data.error);
        }
      }
      else
      {
        console.log("Error in XHR...");
      }
    }, "json");
}
console.log("Let's do this...");
console.log("Setting function doXHR to run every " + interval + " milliseconds...");
setInterval(doXHR, interval);
```

This works perfectly. But if I change the request to, say, `method=category&id=3` (api spec at the link provided), there are no errors, the callbacks and all the `console.log`'s go through just fine, but the wallpaper does not change. I have no idea what the problem is since nothing appears to be "wrong", or even that something different has happened with the code, but the expected out come *does change*.

EDIT: changed the code to reflect Tibrogargan's answer, and the `console.log(index)` statement prints a different number each time, but the same problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

You always get the same element of the returned list (`url:data.wallpapers[>>> 1 <<<].url_image`).  When you use random, that image will almost always be different.  When you use category (for instance), that image is almost always going to be the same image every time.

The only time this will work the way you want is if you use the "random" method in the alphacoders API call.  You will need to implement something to randomly pick an image from the returned list if you want the same behavior from a non-random method.

Replace the index with a variable:

```
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.wallpapers.length);
...
url:data.wallpapers[index].url_image
...
filename:data.wallpapers[index].id...
```

or even better:

```
var wallpaper = data.wallpapers[Math.floor(Math.random() * data.wallpapers.length)];
...
url:wallpaper.url_image,
...
```